# return max value from a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, oop

Update: I have already accepted the answer. However, if anyone could explain about why I got error message "keyerror:1 " in my method 2 in the question, I will be very happy with that. Thank you!

----------------original question ----------------

I 'm completing one exercise, but whatever I have tried,  nothing was correct. I went through all those available answers, still I could not figure it out. The expected answer is described hereinbelow:

The exercise template contains a class named Car which represents the features of a car through two attributes: make (str) and top_speed (int).

Please write a function named fastest_car(cars: list) which takes a list of Car objects as its argument.

The function should return the make of the fastest car. You may assume there will always be a single car with the highest top speed. Do not change the list given as an argument, or make any changes to the Car class definition.

You may use the following code to test your function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    car1 = Car("Saab", 195)
    car2 = Car("Lada", 110)
    car3 = Car("Ferrari", 280)
    car4 = Car("Trabant", 85)

    cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4]
    print(fastest_car(cars))

# Ferrari
```

I have tried like this:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self,make:str,top_speed:int):
    self.make=make
    self.top_speed=top_speed


  def fastest_car(self,list):
    list.sort(key = lambda x : x.top_speed)
    print("Sort by speed")
    print(list)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    car1 = Car("Saab", 195)
    car2 = Car("Lada", 110)
    car3 = Car("Ferrari", 280)
    car4 = Car("Trabant", 85)

    cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4]
   
    Car.fastest_car(cars[-1])


#error message: TypeError: fastest_car() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list'
```

I also tried normal method:

```
#method 2

cars=[{'Saab':195},{'Lada':110},{'Ferrari':280},{'Trabant':85}]

a=sorted(cars,key = lambda x : x[1])
print(a)#just print the sorted list

error message:


----> 3 a=sorted(cars,key = lambda x : x[1])
      4 print(a)

KeyError: 1
```

If you could kindly pointed out what I did wrong, I will highly appreciated. Thank You!

point out mistakes and gain the knowledge

Comment: You're running `Cars.fastest_car(cars[-1])` where `cars[-1]` returns one Car. Just run `cars` instead of indexing it

Comment: @12944qwerty thanks for your answer. got same error message even after I removed [-1] TypeError: fastest_car() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list'

Comment: Ah, `fastest_car` is not a static method. You should probably read on [that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod). Make sure to remove `self` from that.    If you do not wish to use a staticmethod, you can also just do `car1.fastest_car(cars)`

Comment: You're missing the `self` argument. `fastest_car()` should be either an ordinary function or a static method, not an instance method.

Comment: @12944qwerty, after added static method, I got things like [<__main__.Car object at 0x7ff54766c6d0>,..., how can I get the fastest car name then?

Comment: @Barmar, I am open to any solutions. So how should I write the fastest_car as an ordinary function.

Comment: Exactly the same way you wrote it as a method, but without the `self` argument.

Comment: @stel What's wrong with that result? Unless you define a `__repr__()` method, that's how a list of `Car` instances is printed.

Comment: @Barmar, In this exercise, it needed to return fastest. so I change the last line in fastest_car() from print(list) to print(list[-1], then added def __repr__(self):
    return self.make. I got the right answer. But as your another suggestion, without using static method. how should I add self, to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use max() function:

```
fastest_car = max(cars, key=lambda x: x.top_speed)
print(fastest_car.make)
print(fastest_car.top_speed)

>>> out
'''
Ferrari
280
```

UPD

for list of dictionaries you can try this:

```
cars=[{'Saab':195},{'Lada':110},{'Ferrari':280},{'Trabant':85}]

d = {}
for i in cars:
    d.update(i)

max(d,key=d.get)  # 'Ferrari'
```

Comment: thanks. I was thinking about max. I will accept this answer. BTW, can you show the full codes? In my second test, there was no top_speed. I used x[1] and got error

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @12944qwerty and @Barmer's help, this problem is solved like this:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self,make:str,top_speed:int):
    self.make=make
    self.top_speed=top_speed

  @staticmethod
  def fastest_car(list):
    list.sort(key = lambda x : x.top_speed)
    print("Sort by speed")
    return list[-1]
    
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.make


if __name__ == "__main__":
    car1 = Car("Saab", 195)
    car2 = Car("Lada", 110)
    car3 = Car("Ferrari", 280)
    car4 = Car("Trabant", 85)

    cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4]
  
    print(Car.fastest_car(cars))

#result 

Sort by speed
Ferrari
```

I tried also to take that @staticmethod away and I still get the same result. I hope that somebody could explain a little bit why and if possible, someone could tell me what the error message means in that normal method I tried, KeyError: 1
Thanks!

Comment: You can learn more about staticmethods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod)

Comment: @12944qwerty. Thanks. I 've read a little bit from other post. It seems that if I use only in its own class, static method is not compulsory. However, in inhertence cases, it's more recommended. May not correct, but I will take a better look at your link. Thanks!